# Firestore security rule works in simulator but fails in app

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a problem with this Cloud Firestore security rule:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /stages/{stageId} {
      match /collections/{collectionId} {
        match /pois/{poiId} {
          allow read;
          allow write: if request.auth != null || 
            request.method == "update" && 
            request.resource.data.keys() == ["pm"];
          }

        }

    }    
  }
}
```

In code I am trying to update the field `pm` of an existing document as a non-authenticated user with a dictionary of values. The Firestore log shows this request:

```
2018-06-26 12:46:05.476997+0100 app[59292:3472939] 5.3.0 - [Firebase/Firestore][I-FST000001] FSTWriteStream 60c000107230 mutation request: <GCFSWriteRequest 0x60c0006e9e00>: {
    writes {
      update {
        name: "projects/myApp/databases/(default)/documents/stages/dev/collections/ETzbIXBn0Z5FOsCHtHlv/pois/zJELKLTWupuMkYQNb9gl"
        fields {
          key: "pm"
          value {
            map_value {
              fields {
                key: "subLocality"
                value {
                  string_value: "Albufeira"
                }
              }
              fields {
                key: "locality"
                value {
                  string_value: "Albufeira"
                }
              }
              fields {
                key: "country"
                value {
                  string_value: "Portugal"
                }
              }
              fields {
                key: "postalCode"
                value {
                  string_value: "8200-142"
                }
              }
              fields {
                key: "adminArea"
                value {
                  string_value: "Faro"
                }
              }
              fields {
                key: "timezone"
                value {
                  string_value: "Europe/Lisbon"
                }
              }
              fields {
                key: "thoroughfare"
                value {
                  string_value: "Rua Primeiro de Dezembro"
                }
              }
              fields {
                key: "name"
                value {
                  string_value: "Rua Primeiro de Dezembro"
                }
              }
              fields {
                key: "isoCountryCode"
                value {
                  string_value: "PT"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      update_mask {
        field_paths: "pm"
      }
      current_document {
        exists: true
      }
    }
    stream_token: "\031\020hB\002\201\364\265\265"
}
```

**This request fails with "missing or insufficient permissions".**

When I simulate an `update`to `stages/dev/collections/ETzbIXBn0Z5FOsCHtHlv/pois/zJELKLTWupuMkYQNb9gl` with this simulated data

```
{"__name__":"/databases/(default)/documents/stages/dev/collections/ETzbIXBn0Z5FOsCHtHlv/pois/zJELKLTWupuMkYQNb9gl","data":{"pm":{"adminArea":"Germany","testArea":"Munich"}}}
```

the simulator allows the update.

In my code (Swift project/iOS) I am using the `updateData` method on an existing document reference.

As a parameter I am passing this array:

```
["pm": ["adminArea": "Faro", "name": "Rua Primeiro de Dezembro", "postalCode": "8200-142", "locality": "Albufeira", "subLocality": "Albufeira", "isoCountryCode": "PT", "timezone": "Europe/Lisbon", "thoroughfare": "Rua Primeiro de Dezembro", "country": "Portugal"]]
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: @AndréKool I don't need to do this as there is an OR statement after that. The idea is that either authenticated users OR unauthenticated user that only want to update the key "pm" are allowed to write. The security rule simulator also allows access for unauthenticated users, so this is not the problem here. But thanks for looking into the questions!

Comment: Woops, thought it was an AND. My mistake.

Comment: I have never worked with firestore but is it possible to write one level deeper? So instead of writing [pm: data] to location  write data to location/pm (I hope you understand this)

Comment: @AndréKool In general yes, but in this case no, as pm is not a collection but a map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it turns out

```
request.resource.data.keys() == ["pm"];
```

was not working as expected on deployment (even though it worked in the simulator).

Replacing it with

```
request.writeFields.size() == 1 && "pm" in request.writeFields;
```

did the trick for me.

Simulating rules is a great step towards a usable product (Hello Google: Debugging rules ???), but only if they work the same in the simulator as on a live deployment...

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite this

```
request.resource.data.keys() == ["pm"];
```

with

```
request.writeFields == ["pm"];
```